# How do i use datetime or time function in Python for a lucky draw section i am doing?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, shelve

So, currently i kind of make a lucky draw that generates random numbers and assigned it to promo codes (which is lucky draw prize)

i want to make sure that a person can do the lucky draw once a day so after 24 hours, the person can do the lucky draw

since my lucky draw is implemented when you click on a button, i want to set the button such that if you click once, you get a promo code but after that, the button is disabled until 24 hours is up before the person can click on the button again

but since i am not that used to using datetime or time modules, can someone help me to list out what am i supposed to do including the javascript codes to enable and disable button?

thank you

Comment: Please can you add some more context, you have mentioned that you are doing this in python? but then talk about Javascript? Are you doing this in a python framework? I think that the only way to do this would be to make the user login to a system then how it up to a database and then do some sort of php to make sure that they cannot do it within 24 hours, I don't think that you can do it within JS since they could refresh the page or delete history which would undermine your system. Out of interest why can't you use the time module. You could use threading if you are worried about it waiting.

Comment: Yes. I am doing this in a python framework. Python flask im using python and html files together thats where the javascript comes in. For this part, i don't think i can use any php since it is not allowed for this project. I don't really know how to use the time module. Like how to make sure that after 24 hours by using an if statement or something. Sorry i am still new to python and all so yeah

Comment: @Aiyush Basically im trying to store datetime.now() to my database and using that time info to do my javascript. For example , if datetime has passed 24 hours, it will enable the button else the button remain disabled?

Comment: Don't be intimidated by the time module. It is really, really simple. The issue with creating a timer is that you will only be able to have one user at a time as it is only on one thread (I might be incorrect with some of the technicalities here), but to make it work for multiple users you may need to create multiple threads when a user joins/leaves also you will have to create a database of some sort to see what user(s) have joined? By Answering these questions I will be able to help you better: 1. Is this a school project? 2. Is it going out to deployment?. 3 What is your brief for this task

Comment: I only saw your most recent comment now, I cannot give you exact methods on how to achieve this because it requires prerequisite knowledge which you could gain from watching a few python tutorials, but your architecture could work like this: 

1. Make user login
2. Log the time that they clicked the button in the database
3. If they click it again send that value to the database.
4. Compare the two values, if they are x hours away.
5. If so then use your javascript and python to make the button clickable
6. Else delete the last entry until you need to compare the value again.

Comment: @Aiyush  Ooh is that so? What do you mean by threading? My lecturer have not yet mentioned that and yes this is a school project. So, we are supposed to create a website with python classes, shelve, html, flask and etc with functional CRUD (Create,Update,Retrieve,Delete) functions and i am tasked among my group mates to do the lucky draw section part. I am just unsure how to use the timer?

Comment: Hmm. I recommend that you go through a full flask series on YouTube and this will include all the CRUD architecture and then you will be able to implement the time quite easily. Threading:  https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/